# Calling a method from jsp and using it

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

im trying to call a method from a jsp, in order to compare the result with null, this way:

```
<s:if test="%{@registradores.utiles.enumerados.EstadoTramite.tipoMensajeSegunEstado('#attr.listaContatosTable.estado_Nue')!='null'}">
```

But isnt working apparently, it skips always the if, like the result was always false

Full code is:

```
    <s:if test="%{@registradores.utiles.enumerados.EstadoTramite.tipoMensajeSegunEstado('#attr.listaContatosTable.estado_Nue')!='null'}">
        <display:column title="Archivo" headerClass="sortable"
                        defaultorder="descending" style="width:12% ;color:black">
            <s:submit id="botonDescargarNotificacion" value="Notificación"
                      cssClass="boton"
                      onclick="enviarADesde('descargarDocumentoAcuse.action#Notificaciones#', 'formNotificaciones')" />
            &nbsp;
        </display:column>
    </s:if>
```

Btw:

This code works

```
<s:property
    value="%{@registradores.utiles.enumerados.EstadoTramite@tipoMensajeSegunEstado(#attr.listaContatosTable.estado_Nue)}" />
```

Comment: I updated my answer, I didnt notice that you were using struts. It should probably work if you remove the quotes from `null`

Comment: Which one of the solutions worked? I want to edit the answer so people know the correct answer if they stuble into the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, in my case the second one

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. Good luck with your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a long time since I used JSP last.

Could you please try this out and let me know if it worked?

```
<s:if test="%{@registradores.utiles.enumerados.EstadoTramite.tipoMensajeSegunEstado('#attr.listaContatosTable.estado_Nue')!=null}">
```

Comment: it's incorrect OGNL expression, static method access is disabled by default.